# Django form not showing input fields

Tags: python, html, django

I've tried to fix this issue with chat GPT for a while now, but it says that everything okay, but it clearly ain't. For now I;m trying to just run  the e-mail field before doing the rest. Here are my files:
forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    isOwner = forms.BooleanField()
```

the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}" class="registerForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div class="header">Registration</div>

        <div class="loginText">E-mail:</div>
        <div class="loginInformation">
            {{ form.email.label_tag }}
            {{ form.email }}
        </div>

    </form>
```

and my controller:

```
@api_view(('GET', 'POST',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            account = accountService.signup(
                request.POST["email"],
                request.POST["password"],
                request.POST["firstName"],
                request.POST["lastName"],
                request.POST["isOwner"]
            )
            if account:
                return Response({'account': account}, template_name="index.html")
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, "signup.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: Maybe you should replace your `@api_view` with `@api_view(('GET', 'POST',))`

Comment: Also, put back the `form = SignupForm(request.POST)` where it belongs, just below the `if request.method == "POST" :`

Comment: Hey, done as said, form = SignupForm(request.POST) is back in the if statement, added 'get' to in the @view, still not showing up, tried on both opera and edge

Comment: What is the result? Share us the rendered code of your form. No error on the console? No error on the browser?

Comment: yeah, that's correct, no errors when running the page at all. The only thing that might be helpful, at the end of the             
account = accountService.signup(
                request.POST["email"],
            ) 
fragment, it shows a warning "parameter 'x' unfilled"

Comment: Use edge [DevTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/overview) and copy / paste the form part of your rendered HTML please

Comment: Hey, thanks, I see the input field is being set to invisible for some reason... I will investigate it tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help so far

Comment: Hey, just managed it to work. I've put the resolution in the original post. Thanks for you help

Comment: sure, done it :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write context data for render

Comment: Hey, do you mean my urls.py? Sorry I'm still a newbie

Comment: No in your controller at end instead of , return render(request, "signup.html") write, return render(request, "signup.html" , {"form":form})

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated the controller, but it still doesn't show up, i've might have mixed it up?

Comment: In your template, you're using {{ form.as_p }} and also trying to render the email field separately. The {{ form.as_p }} will render all fields in the form as paragraph elements. If you want to render fields manually, you don't need to use {{ form.as_p }}. You should only render the fields individually. For example, for the email field, you can use:
    <div class="loginText">E-mail:</div>
    <div class="loginInformation">
        {{ form.email.label_tag }}
        {{ form.email }}
    </div>

Comment: Hey, I've found the issue, I've added it to the original post. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I've been using 2 seperate functions, one to access the registration page:

```py
def getSignupForm(request):
    return render(request, "signup.html")
```

and second one to create the form `signup(request)` from above.

I though Django will be able to run this funtion with this part of the form `action="{% url 'signup' %}"`, but it doesn't... I just had to change the onlick action on my button to run the signup function instead of `getSignupForm`. FML